# mailgun.js inline image attachments

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, email-attachments, mailgun

I want to embed inline images with mailgun, however the documentation for sending attachments doesnt seem to match with the latest `mailgun.js` **NOT `mailgun-js`**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun.js

the mentioned docs in this readme do not exist: https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#sending << 404's

The readme docs for this version say this:
[image]

But where do I even add an attachment? How do I set mailgun to use `multipart/form-data` encoding? Where/ what parameter do I use to add an attachment? There are no good type definitions either

If i have this code below, how do I just add an attachment? What's the object schema? Does it even go here? I have no clue

```js
mg.messages.create('sandbox-123.mailgun.org', {
    from: "Excited User <mailgun@sandbox-123.mailgun.org>",
    to: ["test@example.com"],
    subject: "Hello",
    text: "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!",
    html: "<h1>Testing some Mailgun awesomness!</h1>"
  })
```

Even once set as an attachment, how do I reference it in the email to use in `<img>` ?

Anyone that has done with the latest `mailgun.js` please share your reference code. The documentation is outdated

Answer (score 6):

The documentation of `mailgun.js` can be a bit confusing, at least for node JS, since their website refers to the old version SDK whereas their github page points to the new one. That said, their [github page](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-js#create) does offer examples for including figures in the email. There are two ways to do so

- Sent as attachment files but **NOT displayed in the email**.
- Sent as inline figure and displayed in the email.

Below shows an example (original code available [here](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-js/blob/master/examples/send-email.js)) of sending figures both as attachment and inline. Notice that for inline figures to display, one must anchor the file name with a prefix `cid:` in an HTML template.

To send multiple attachments or inline figures, include all files in a list (the example below uses a list of one file for both inline and attachment).

```js
/**
Copied from https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-js/blob/master/examples/send-email.js
*/

const fs = require('fs');
const domain = 'sandbox-123.mailgun.com';
const fromEmail = 'Excited User <mailgun@sandbox-123.mailgun.com>';
const toEmails = ['you@example.com'];

const mailgunLogo = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/mailgun.png`);
const rackspaceLogo = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/rackspace.png`);

mg.messages.create(domain, {
  from: fromEmail,
  to: toEmails,
  subject: 'Hello',
  html: '<img src="cid:mailgun.png" width="200px"><br><h3>Testing some Mailgun awesomness!</h3>',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!',
  inline: [mailgunLogo],
  attachment: [rackspaceLogo]
})
  .then((msg) => console.log(msg))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me hours of frustration.